# NestJS trying to open an image within the project inside a folder through an url

Tags: nestjs

I have this project made in NestJS which I am using to build Endpoints. Recently I have created an endpoint to save images, those images are being saved inside a folder (called upload) at the same level that the SRC folder.

I need to open those images, like this: http://localhost:3000/upload/2363729-c9642363729.jpg

but as much as I try, I can't get it.

This is my main.ts code (it's not working now):

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { NestExpressApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import path, { join } from 'path';
import * as express from 'express';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(
    AppModule,
  );
  app.enableCors();
  app.useStaticAssets(path.join(__dirname, '/../update'));
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

but this is how it used to be:

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.enableCors();
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

this is how it looks like my project:

[image]

how can I get the url please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your code, `update` instead of `upload`. Replace it with this:

`app.useStaticAssets(path.join(__dirname, '../upload'));`

Comment: oh lol, you are right, I didn't even notice. Thank you